# encoding decoding Json using RSA Angular and Express.js

Tags: json, express, encryption, rsa, angular13

I have a frontend Angular.ts and a backend Express.js. I am decrypting user credentials in the frontend using RSA and sending all the data as an encrypted string to the backend.
When I try to catch the data in the backend to decrypt it, it reads the received object as [object Object] which makes it impossible to decrypt. This is the code =>:

**FRONTEND** *httpService.ts*:

```
   sendmail(user: { name: any; email: any; host: any }) {
    console.log(user);
    const encJsonUser = this.rsaHelper.encryptWithPublicKey(
        JSON.stringify(user)
    );
    console.log(encJsonUser);
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/sendemail', encJsonUser);
  }
```

**BACKEND***email.js*:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let path = null;
    const encryptedData = req.body;
    console.log("RECEIVED ENCRYPTED BODY: " + encryptedData);

    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("privateKey.key.pem", "utf8");
    console.log("toDecryptData::: " + encryptedData);

    const decryptedData = decryptedDataFromAngular(encryptedData, privateKey);
    console.log("DECRYPTED-DATA: " + decryptedData);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/pdf", {host: encryptedData.host}).then(async function (response) {
        path = response.data.scan_id;

    }).then(() => {
        emailPdfGenerator(encryptedData);
    });
})

function decryptedDataFromAngular(encryptedData, privateKey) {
    // encryptedData = Buffer.from(encryptedData, "base64");
    const body = JSON.parse(encryptedData);
    // console.log("ENCRYPTED DATA 2222:::: " + encryptedData);
    console.log("ENCRYPTED DATA 2222:::: " + body);
    const decryptedData = crypto.privateDecrypt(
        {
            key: privateKey,
            // In order to decrypt the data, we need to specify the
            // same hashing function and padding scheme that we used to
            // encrypt the data in the previous step
            padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
            oaepHash: "sha256",
        },
        body
    );
    console.log("decrypted data: ", decryptedData.toString());
    console.log("DE RAW DATA" + decryptedData);
    return decryptedData;
}
```

error message:

> RECEIVED ENCRYPTED BODY: [object Object] toDecryptData::: [object Object] undefined:1 [object Object]  ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()
> at decryptedDataFromAngular (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\routes\email.js:60:23)
> at C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\routes\email.js:31:27
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
> at next (C:\Users\hayan\Desktop\HSLeiden\Year2-IN2B\IPSEN5\Security-Check-Express-User\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: RSA is an cryptographic algorithm so you don't encode/decode but encrypt/decrypt data. But RSA is not capable of processing data of arbitrary size and there are some attacks when RSA is directly used to encrypt user data, therefore in general it is not recommended to use RSA for data encryption, instead use a hybrid encryption: Encrypt data with random AES key and the encrypt AES key with RSA.

Comment: It is a good point, but for now, my problem is more by “Not being able to read the data coming from the frontend”. Any idea how to fix that?

As far as I could see, that data(JSON) was well encrypted as a whole, and therefore, it is not able to read it in the backend.
@Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped using crypto, and I am using forge to solve the problem because crypto just didn't help me.
This is my code:

```
async function decryptUser(encryptedUserData) {
    const name = await decryptString(encryptedUserData.name);
    const email = await decryptString(encryptedUserData.email);
    const host = await decryptString(encryptedUserData.host);

    const decryptedUser = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        host: host,
    }
    return decryptedUser

}

async function decryptString(encryptedString) {
    const rsa = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await rsa.decrypt(encryptedString);
}
```